# Select count votes for each object and top voted objects

Tags: mysql, count, foreign-key-relationship

I have two tables :

VOTE with fields `pk:id, fk:uid, date` and SUBMISSION with fields `pk:id, ...`.

Tables have 1to1 relation on uid<-id fields. How I can now query for :

- list of objects together with their score
- list of 10 top rated objects ordered by score ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    SELECT s.*,
           COUNT(*) AS cnt
      FROM SUBMISSION s
INNER JOIN VOTE v ON s.id = v.uid
  GROUP BY s.id
  ORDER BY cnt DESC
     LIMIT 10
```

Without `ORDER BY` and `GROUP BY` clauses you'll just retrieve all the submissions with votes count.

But I **highly recommend** you to create `votes_count` field in the `SUBMISSION` table and maintain it with trigger/code to store the precalculated count of votes there.